# Check for mail server SMTPUTF8 support

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a system where (registered) users have the possibility to add their own SMTP server for mail sending. Thus I don't know in advance what server a user might add and whether this one supports   SMTPUTF8. Now starting from JavaMail 1.6 [support](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases/tag/JAVAMAIL-1_6_0) for SMTPUTF8 has been added.
After enabling this for some servers the following line is printed to the log:

> mail.mime.allowutf8 set but server doesn't advertise SMTPUTF8 support

This is correct for that server, however how can I detect whether a server supports this or not? I see two possibilities:

1. Somehow detect whether a mail server supports SMTPUTF8 - if that is possible?
2. Add another parameter to the stmp configuration and then the users decide (which in most cases they don't really know I would guess)

So is there a way to detect whether a server supports SMTPUTF8?

I checked the implementation and the [com.sun.mail.SMTPTransport](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java) seems to provide such a query possibility.

`public boolean supportsExtension(String ext)`

So calling

```
SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(...);
boolean smtputf8 = transport.supportsExtension("SMTPUTF8");
```

should work. It is using an `EHLO command` (defined in rfc1869) when connecting to the server. However in my implementation I just call

```
...
Transport.send(Message msg);
```

So I do not directly access SMTPTransport. One should not directly access `com.sun` packages, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ESMTP with the EHLO command one can query the smtp server for supported extensions. `mail.smtp.ehlo=true;` must be enabled.

```
boolean detectUTF8(String smtpServerHost, int smtpServerPort,  String smtpUserName, String smtpUserAccessToken) {
    
    Transport transport = null;
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        //session.setDebug(true);

        transport = session.getTransport();
        transport.connect(smtpServerHost, smtpServerPort, smtpUserName, smtpUserAccessToken);
            
        if(transport instanceof SMTPTransport || transport instanceof SMTPSSLTransport) {
            return ((SMTPTransport)transport).supportsExtension("SMTPUTF8");
        }
        return false;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        //Proper loggin & exception handling!!!
        //return false;
    }
    finally {
        if(transport!=null) {
            try {
                transport.close();
            }
            catch (MessagingException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice if the `supportsExtension(...)` method would make it into the [Transport](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/javax/mail/Transport.java) interface so that `javax.mail` could be used.